# не могу подключить библиотеку из github

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle, jitpack.io

При попытке подключения [этой](https://github.com/29jitender/Spotlight?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3730) библиотеки появляются следующие ошибки.

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.wooplr:Spotlight:1.2.3.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.wooplr:Spotlight:1.2.3.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.wooplr:Spotlight:1.2.3.
```

Мой файл build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.wooplr:Spotlight:1.2.3'
}
```

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

offline mod отключен,
пробовал отключить/включить vpn,
зависимости без `maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}` подключаются без нареканий

вычитал что проблема может быть в настройках gradle/ide/машины. где мне найти эти настройки или как настроить или может снести студию и поставить заново??

Comment: Попробуйте repositories убрать из buildscript, возможно, оно перезатирает то, что указано в allprojects

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov попробовал, появляется ошибка: не может найти репозитории

Comment: попробуйте тогда туда maven() добавить

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov ругается на то, что не может разрешить 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я нашел в чем проблема. В gradle.properties у меня были следующие строки

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=163.172.136.226
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8811
systemProp.https.proxyHost=163.172.136.226
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8811
```

я так понимаю это настройки прокси. Я их удалил и теперь все работает как и должно работать